# jquery: two ways to use the click() method

Tags: jquery

In my `jquery` app I'm triggering a mouse click invoking `$("#id").click();`.

I'm seeing, however, that with this syntax (which should be the correct one), the click event has the `which` property *undefined*.

While invoking `$("#id")[0].click();` (which I cannot fint documented on `jquery` site) I get the `ev.which` property set to 1. That's is exactly what I'm interested in, but I cannot understand why I get it.

My questions are:

- is the second form correct?
- what is the meaning of using on html code a method defined for a
  jquery object?
- why is the behaviour different?

Comment: `$(selector)[0]` gives you a DOM node, *not* a jquery object, so you won't find details of this on the jquery site, try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: Using jQuery you can use:  $("#id").trigger( "click" ). For more details take a look to [.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Also note that `.which` is *non-standard*, so shouldn't be used unless you can control which browsers are using your site.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which